# format phone no is us style eg: (xxx)xxx-xxx

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I format plain 10 digit phone no. to us style **(xxx)-xxx-xxxx** using javascript regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it: [`^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$`](https://regex101.com/r/oI1mP6/1)

Here is a working example:

```js
var testNumber = '1234567890';
var regex = /^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/;
var sub = '($1)-$2-$3';

var usNumber = testNumber.replace(regex, sub);

alert(usNumber);
```